# can not add marker to osmdroid offline map

Tags: android, osmdroid

i try to add a maker to osmdroid map.

the code like this:

```
    markerDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.offline_marker);
mapView_offline.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapController_offline.setZoom(zoomLevel);
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);

        OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(title, description, point);
        item.setMarker(markerDrawable);
        ArrayList<OverlayItem> list = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        list.add(item);
        ItemizedIconOverlay overyLay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(
                list, markerDrawable, this, resProxy);
        mapView_offline.getOverlays().add(overyLay);
        mapController_offline.setCenter(point);
```

then , the mapView_offline can show the map. but maker never get show.

and i am using MBtiles file as offline map source. To use MBtiles file source, i added MBTileModuleProvider,MBTileProvider,MBTileSource  from 
http://www.sieswerda.net/2012/08/15/upping-the-developer-friendliness/

what's the problem??

Comment: What kind of Drawable is markerDrawable?

Comment: markerDrawable just a png image